# What's Arunam mantra or Arunaprasna?

Tags: mantras, yajur-veda

What's Arunam mantra or Arunaprashna. Please explain the importance, origin of Arunam.
Is it okay, or allowed to chant ArunaPrashna in front of Lord Vishnu or other Goddessess?

Comment: This is basically Surya Mantra and you can find similar answers on the forum. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13904/11875 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14422/11875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Aruna Prashna is part of the Taittiriya Aranyaka of the Krishna Yajurveda.

From the preface of the book ["Essence of Taittiriya Aranyaka"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/ESSENCE_OF_TAITTIRIYA_ARANYAKA.pdf):

> Taittiriya Aranyaka‟ (Part 1) covers 10 chapters of which 6 are
> Aranyaka proper. **The first chapter of Aruna Prashna deals with the
> daily duties of „shrotriya brahmanas‟**; Parashara Smriti aptly
> details the „Shat Karmas‟: Sandhyaa snaanam japo homo Devataanamcha
> pujanam, Vishwa Devaatithi yaamcha shatkarmaani diney diney/ or
> Sandhya Vandana after „baahyaantara shuchi‟ or external and internal
> cleanliness-Japa-Homa- Devatarchana and Puja- and vishwa deva-athithi
> seva. The second chapter discusses Pancha Maha Yagjnas to be observed
> daily viz. Deva Yagjna-Pirtu Yagjna-Bhuta YagjnaManushya Yagjna and
> Brahma Yagjna. Chapter 3 deals with the intricacies of homa karyas and
> Yagjnas. The Chapters 4 and 5 are worthy of avoidance as those are of
> rather risky contents of applied shrouta rituals. Chapter 6 relate to
> pitrumedha mantras and pitrumedha rituals of post- life relevance. The
> Chapters of 7-8-9 are „vallis‟ viz. Shiksha- Bhrigu and Ananda vallis,
> anchored to Taittiriya Upanishad. The 10th chapter is Maha
> Narayaonopanishad. An important highlight of this Script is the
> „Manasika Yagjna‟ which has ready applicability to the present
> generation; one may not be able to execute Agni Karyas or even time
> for Introspection with- standing the harsh winds of materialism and
> family responsibilities.

Aruna Prashna is comprised of Mantras dedicated to Lord Surya as said below:

> **PRASHNA I.**
>
> [**This Aruna Prashna I has the following 32 Anuvakas essentially
> devoted to Surya Deva named Aditya the son of Aditi,** the origin of
> Mystery and Perpetuity; very first Stanza of „ Prathama Mandala, Sukta
> 115 of Rig Veda states Chitram devaanaamudagaadaneekam
> chakshurmitrasya Varunasyaagneh, aapraadyaavaaprithivee antariksham
> Surya aatmaa jagatastadyushashchah/Jangama sthaavara jagat‟ or the
> world of mobile and immobile creation gets admirably activised by the
> emergence of Surya Deva on the Sky and his awesome appearance by the
> day break; Mitra-Varuna and the other Devas there along as also the
> attendant Devis on the firmament get warmed up and visualised not only
> by the Beings of Bhuloka but also of the dyuloka and antariksha too
> get filled up with splendour totally!

Comment: Dhanyosmi , Rickross ji !! _/\_

Comment: @SaMolWT Why a new account?

Comment: Pranaams Rickrross. ji.... simply :-) ... ..                                                                                   
may i know your contact number./mail id

Comment: Pranams ... I think giving personal contact details is not allowed on this site :) @SaMolWT

Comment: @SaMolWT I am willing to give you my mail but if I do it here, everyone else can see it too which I don't want .. then tell me what to do now?